# Delete Row From asp GridView and From Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, viewstate

I have asp gridview which is bind with a datatable. Only one template column that is checkbox is bind with source datatable column (`sel`).

Here is markup example:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="testGrid"  
                CssClass="ObjSelection" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                OnRowDataBound="testGrid_RowDataBound"
                runat="server">
 <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="&nbsp">
        <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sel")%>' OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_OnCheckChange" />
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>                                   

 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As you see, I am not using RowCommand to delete a row. I have a toolbar in a separate `div`, which shows delete button.

Can you guide how could I delete a row `both from DataSource and GridView` on a button click which exists in another `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to remove selected row from datatable which is either in ViewState or in Session and assign data source

Aslo assign datakey to GridView

```
<asp:GridView  ID="testGrid"    DataKeyNames="PrimaryKey" 
                CssClass="ObjSelection" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                OnRowDataBound="testGrid_RowDataBound"
                runat="server">
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void btnRemove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check session exists 
        if (Session["Key"] != null)
        {
            // Opening / Retreiving DataTable.
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Key"];

            foreach (GridViewRow row in testGrid.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow= row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox;

                if (chkRow!= null && chkRow.Checked)
                {                    
                    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(testGrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value); 

                    DataRow[] drs = dt.Select("PrimaryKey = '" + Id + "'"); // replace with your criteria as appropriate

                    if (drs.Length > 0)
                    {
                        dt .Rows.Remove(drs[0]);
                    }
                }
            }

            Session["Key"] = dt ;
            testGrid.DataSource = dt ;
            testGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden field to put id of row by javascript and Jquery

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="IDField"/>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#testGrid tr").click(function(){
              $("#IDField").val($(this).children("td.IDColumn").text());
              $(this).Index(); // will give you row index
              });
});
</script>
```

click delete button

```
protected void delete_Click(object sender,EventArg e)
{
 //delete from datasource use this.IDField.Value   

//to refresh data in grid 
this.testGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
this.testGrid.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: How would get the index of the row that is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
gridview_RowDataBound(Sender sender,eventArgs e)
{
CheckBox lblChkRow = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("IDField");
if(lblChkRow.Checked)
{
// Delete Value here and bind with datasource

}
```